# How to Set or Increase Number of Persistent HTTP Connections in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, http, wsdl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Max number of concurrent HttpWebRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361771/max-number-of-concurrent-httpwebrequests)

I have an application (C#/.NET 4.0) which is consuming a WSDL service which is prohibitively slow, and I need to send requests in large quantities.

I am parallellizing the operation by creating several `Thread`s to manage the requests. However, I'm running into the maximum 2 persistent HTTP connections allowed: if I run two threads, they both come back with 400ms turnarounds. If I run four threads, they all come back with 800ms turnarounds because they're being serialized through only two connections.

Interestingly, if I spawn several instances of the same proof-of-concept application, running two threads each, they **all** run with 400ms turnaround per thread; thus, the connection is per-instance rather than per-machine or -NIC.

How can I increase the number of persistent connections that my application will use?

*(In case this is a vital detail, it's running over HTTPS)*

**Answer** for when it's closed: It's a web/app.config setting.

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="800"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Wow, I looked for that for so long and investigated every single linked article that stack threw at me. Good call, thank you.

Comment: You bet, give a shout back if that doesn't work.

Comment: Already done, works perfectly.