# Multiple HttpWebRequest with POST at the same time

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, httpwebrequest

I am trying to send the POST requests to the web server, they all have to be done at the same time.
I've made the code below, but it's sending the requests about 4 per second. For example, if I want to send 20 POST requests, it will take about 6 seconds, and they're not sent simultaneously as I want.
I have tried to set ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit and ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints higher, but it's still the same.

```
class BrowserAsync
{
    private HttpWebRequest WebReq;

    public void makePOST(string url, string POST)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(POST);
        WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        WebReq.Headers.Clear();
        // CUSTOM HEADERS HERE -- not shown in this example

        WebReq.KeepAlive = false;
        WebReq.Proxy = null;

        WebReq.Method = "POST";
        WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

        Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
        PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        PostData.Close();

        WebReq.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), null);
    }

    private void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // data returned is not important, just end it
        WebReq.EndGetResponse(result);
    }
}
```

Every instance is getting called from it's own thread:

```
public static void waitAndExecute(object threadInfo)
{
    // this is the thread on it's own
    ThreadInformation info;
    info = (ThreadInformation)threadInfo;

    // WAIT
    // Display("Sleeping until " + DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds((info.exTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds - info.ping)
    // the same sleeping time is displayed for all threads
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)(info.exTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds - info.ping);

    BrowserAsync brw = new BrowserAsync();
    brw.makePOST("url", info.postParameters);
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Are you getting an error? What's your expected result, and what result are you getting?

Comment: I want to send 20 POSTs at the same time. I'm not getting any errors. The result is that first 4 posts are sent in 1st second, the other 4 are then sent in 2nd second, etc ...

Comment: What code do you use to call the waitAndExecute method 20 times? Also what sets the exTime and ping properties of info?

Comment: It's a long and complicated method. exTime and ping properties are all the same for all 20 threads. They're set by that method ("long and complicated").

Comment: A long and complicated method that might take 0.25 seconds to kick off each thread?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `HttpClient` and `PostAsync`.

You can pass the second parameter HttpContent using the `StringContent` class e.g.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(POST));
```

See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13155225/1202600 for an example of kicking all the requests off at the same time but with `GetAsync`