# Winforms app freeze after calling a series of async methods

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I am working on a winforms application with async methods. On an event i call multiple series of async methods.
Unfortunately, the application freezes. My async calls are all awaited but i couldnt figure out what caused the deadlock.

Winforms block

```
    private async void sendMessages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         await ServiceFacade.SendMessage("Hi to CEO");
         await ServiceFacade.SendMessage("Hi to Manager");
         await ServiceFacade.SendMessage("Hi to Team Leader");
    }
```

My library class which sends data to an api

```
   public class ServiceFacade
   {

   public  async Task SendMessage(string message)
   {

       //validates and formats message then calls PostAsync to send it on api service

       await PostAsync(string message);
   }

   private static async Task PostAsync(string message)
   {

       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("hostname.com")
       //set up REQUEST ...
       var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
   }

   }
```

Comment: @musefan i waited for about 30mins an my app is still freezed. i also set my request to 60 seconds.

Comment: On the off chance that your actual code is more complicated, are you using Task.Wait() anywhere within the async flow? It sounds like you're aware of this already, so I assume not.

Comment: @john
i did not since it will block the context.
all of my tasks are awaited.
 i am so puzzled how this resulted on deadlock.

Comment: Just to confirm, I've reproduced it at my end, but I'm unsure why it's happening. I'll see what I can find out :)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/WebRequest.cs#L898-L931) is the source code for WebRequest.

Comment: "Offload to a different thread to avoid blocking"

will setting await be enough? im new to async/await :(

Comment: You want to know something weird? If I only make two requests in a row, it works... it gets stuck on the third one.

Comment: It seems related to the accepted answer here (increasing the max connections allowed all of my requests to operate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361771/max-number-of-concurrent-httpwebrequests
 - I suspect there's a bug when you're using it asynchronously which prevents it from returning an error / waiting correctly. I'd recommend switching to HttpClient (I've experienced none of these issues with it.)